# white space validation not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

forms.py

I want to validate white space for following fields name1,name2 and name3.I tried the same in clean(),where i did other validation.Only white space validation is not accepting.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `blank` is set to `False` on the model?

Comment: Yes,blank is set to False on model.

Comment: Why are you opening multiple question for same problem?

Comment: Because,earlier one the answer was for individual field,i don't know how to write white space validation for whole form using clean() method.Question again asked with tried sample.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a RegexField, which would only accept the formats (incl whitespace) you want?

See [RegexField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#regexfield) in the docs

Comment: Can you provide me a sample link or example ,how to start